# Connecting to a Ledger wallet with Web3.js

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, ledger, ledger-nano

I currently have a web app that uses web3.js to connect to Phantom wallets and sign with a relatively straightforward code snippet below:

```
const response = await solana.connect();
const message = 'Please confirm wallet ownership.';
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
const signedMessage = await window.solana.signMessage(encodedMessage, 'utf8');
// Does stuff with signedMessage
```

However, this approach does not work with Ledger wallets. The connection and sign message popups appear as normal, but after confirming on the Ledger, nothing happens. Is there another confirmation/check needed to verify the Ledger approved the signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing messages in this way is presently not supported. Follow along here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/21366